# Circular loader not showing using reactstrap Spinner

Tags: css, reactjs, reactstrap

I'm trying to simply show loader using `reactstrap (v^7.1.0)` `Spinner` component.  like

```
<Spinner color="warning" />
```

but not showing on screen. When I inspect the page in Chrome, seems CSS not present for Spinner.

[image]
Any idea how to fix?

Thanks,

Comment: which Bootstrap version are you using? Spinners was added since v4.2.0

Comment: @UladzislauUlasenka using v4.1.3

Comment: it works on updating bootstrap to v4.2.1:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading to "bootstrap": "v4.2.0" or higher solved this for me

> Spinner loading component was added in bootstrap v4.2.0

[click here to know more](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v4.2.0)

https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css